# Tikhonov regularization using Newton's method or gradient descent

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, newton-raphson, inverse-problems

In [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization#Tikhonov_regularization) an explicit solution denoted by $\hat {x}$, is given by

$$ \hat{x} = (A^TA + \Gamma^T\Gamma)^{-1}A^Tb$$

How can we solve the same problem using Newton's method or gradient descent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Math StackExchange!

Yes, you can. In this case, the loss function is given by
$${\displaystyle \mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}) = \|A\mathbf {x} -\mathbf {b} \|_{2}^{2}+\|\Gamma \mathbf {x} \|_{2}^{2}}$$
so the gradient of it is
$$\nabla_{\mathbf{x}}\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}) = \nabla_{\mathbf{x}}(\|A\mathbf {x} -\mathbf {b} \|_{2}^{2}) + \nabla_{\mathbf{x}}(\|\Gamma \mathbf {x} \|_{2}^{2}) = (2A^\top A \mathbf{x} - 2A^\top b) + (2\Gamma^\top \Gamma \mathbf{x}).$$
Also, the hessian is given by
$$\text{Hess} \;\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}) = 2(A^\top A + \Gamma^\top \Gamma).$$

With this gradient and this hessian, you can apply Newton's method or gradient descent.

Comment: To be clear, Newton's method in general also requires one to compute a Hessian. In this case however, the Hessian is constant (w.r.t. $x$), so it ends up being the same as gradient descent with a particular step size.

Comment: Nice clarification! I updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: No, Newton's method will be notably different from gradient descent. The former converges in one step (the problem is quadratic) and the latter will not.

Comment: @Dirk Oops, yes you are absolutely right; Newton's method approximates the objective function with a quadratic, but the objective function here is already quadratic, so one step suffices. Newton's method requires inversion of the Hessian, which is exactly the inverse term in the explicit solution.

Comment: Thank you both very informative answers!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by user326159 does calculate the gradient correctly. If you apply gradient descent you will get some kind of damped Landweber iteration and this will converge to the unique minimizer of the Tikhonov function (if you choose the stepsize not too large).

However, if you apply Newtons method, you will get the exact minimizer of the Tikhnov functional (the one you gave in your questions) in just one step.